# How to prevent data throttling with audio codec streaming

Tags: audio, codec, bitrate

I am sampling a incoming audio stream at 8Ksps. I have a codec that takes ~1.6ms to encode a packet of data (80 samples) into  an encoded packet (5 samples). At this rate I get 8000*1.662e-3 ~= 13 samples every encoding cycle. But I need 80 samples every cycle. How do I keep the stream continuous? My only guess is slow down the bitrate of the outgoing encode stream but I'm not sure how to calculate this in general such that buffers on the incoming side don't fill up and the receiving side's buffers don't get starved.

This seems like a basic tenet of streaming but I can't find any info on methods. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Encoding is not typically done in a realtime streaming environment. Encoders are often more processor intensive than decoders are. If your encoder output cannot keep up with the stream requirements then you're out of luck unless you can tolerate a lot of buffering.

Comment: I can both encode and decode a stream without throttling the data. I'm saying I want to just encode and stream it but change the bitrate so that the stream is unbroken.

Comment: And how is encoding not typically done in a streaming environment? All routers, satellites, etc. compress data before they send it.

Comment: I think I was misread your post and assumed that you were running out of CPU cycles in trying to keep up with the encoding process. From there I assumed you might be running an encoder that is asymmetrical (e.g. dolby digital) where the encoding is much more heavyweight than the decoding is an typically happens in batch. So is your issue that your input and output bit rates are the same but there is data compression in the middle so you do not have enough output samples to fill the output?